# Active Class in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, class

I have Nav menu in HTML and im trying to achieve an easy method to highlight the active page.
The method im using currently is

**Calling this in my HTML**

```
<?php $var = 27; include('PHP/HTML-NavigationBar.php'); ?>
```

**PHP Nav Menu**

```
<a class="<?php echo (($var==27)?'active':'');?>" href="Text.php">Text</a>
<a class="<?php echo (($var==28)?'active':'');?>" href="Text2.php">Text2</a>
```

**active** is a class used to highlight a particular Nav.
Im currently calling the **var** in every HTML File. 
I also have a NextPage and a PrevPage button which i manually have to mention next and prev pages names.
Is there anyway to automate this where i could get the number of the present page and add 1 to that when i click on the next page and minus 1 when i click on prev? And also any alternative for specifying the number in every layout as the number of pages is getting higher. I dont mind a suggestion including HTML/CSS/JavaScript or PHP

Next and Prev Button

```
<a href="Prev.php" class="buttonprev"> Previous </a>
<a href="Next.php" class="buttonnext"> Next </a>
```

Comment: `$var + 1` ? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes but how do i implement that here? @B001ᛦ

Comment: Does it have to be done in PHP?

Comment: PHP JavaScript or HTML/CSS anything is fine @MattHamer5

Comment: Why not links with a GET parameter `<a href="mypage.php?page=<?= $var+1 ?>" class="buttonnext"> Next </a>` or to get beautiful URLs use the same function in a loop of nav menu and buttons while lookingup from database.

Comment: How will i get the item clicks value? as you can see im switching between pages manually @Quasimodo'sclone

Comment: It is unclear why you are hardcoding `$var = 27`.

Comment: That piece of code is more Highlighting the current Page. 27 is the 27th page and in the PHP File the 27th nav item would be highlighted @Quasimodo'sclone

Comment: I would put all the URLs in an array or a database.

Comment: I'll just put the URLs in a new PHP file. so after that what can be done? @Quasimodo'sclone

Answer (score 0):

if you decide to go with a php file to host links, just create an array within that:

```
$nav_items = array(
    1 => array("Text1.php", "Navigation title 1"),
    2 => array("Text2.php", "Navigation title 2"),
    3 => array("Text3.php", "Navigation title 3"),
    4 => array("Text4.php", "Navigation title 4"),
);
```

Than in your code you reference it like so:

```
foreach ($nav_items as $key => $value) {
  $class = "";
  if($key == $var) { 
    $class = "active"; 
  }
  echo '<a class="'.$class.'" href="'.$value[0].'">'.$value[1].'</a>';
}
```

Haven't tested it yet, but it should work fine. 
You would still need to define $var on each page though.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold the URLs and titles in an array (or fetch it from database). Then you can iterate over it within a function and calculate the previous/next page within another function. You can use e.g. the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable to figure out which page has been requested.

```
<?php
function navigation() // just not to spam namespace with variables
{
  $pages = // you can fetch this from database as well
  [
    [ 'url' => '/demo/some-page.php'       , 'title' => 'some page' ],
    [ 'url' => '/demo/another-page.php'    , 'title' => 'another page' ],
    [ 'url' => '/demo/yet-another-page.php', 'title' => 'yet another page' ],
    [ 'url' => '/demo/last-page.php'       , 'title' => 'last page' ],
  ];

  $index = array_search($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], array_column($pages, 'url'));

  $nav_list = function() use ($pages, $index)
  {
?>
  <ul>
<?php
    foreach ($pages as $k => $v)
    {
?>
    <li> <a class="<?= $index === $k ? 'active':'' ?>" href="<?= $v['url']?>"><?= $v['title']?></a> </li>
<?php
    }
?>
  </ul>
<?php
  };

  $prev_next = function() use($pages, $index)
  {
    if(false !== $index)
    {
      if($index > 0)
      {
        $v = $pages[$index - 1];
      ?>
        <a class="buttonprev" href="<?=$v['url']?>"><?=$v['title']?></a>
      <?php
      }

      if($index < count($pages) - 1)
      {
        $v = $pages[$index + 1];
      ?>
        <a class="buttonnext" href="<?=$v['url']?>"><?=$v['title']?></a>
      <?php
      }
    }
  };

  return [$nav_list, $prev_next];
}

[$nav_list, $prev_next] = navigation();
```

In your hardcoded page file you just include that and call the functions:

```
<?php
require_once 'nav.php';

$nav_list();
$prev_next();
```